# D3 chart like the US government analytics

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I want to modify charts I have used in D3 to be like those on the US government analytics. I am unsure where to start. The JSfiddle below is where I am starting from.

Do I have to modify the chart to a stacked bar chart, a bullet chart or simply create the recs and add more space between them and position labels above the charts?

Has anyone done anything similar with D3?

My starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/Monduiz/drhdtsaq/

The Y axis, rects and labels:

```
[...]

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["Earnings", "Industry", "Housing", "Jobs"])
    .rangeRoundBands([0, height], 0.2);

[...]

bar.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 0)
    .attr("height", barHeight - 1)
    .attr("fill", "#9D489A")
    .attr("width", function(d){return x(d.value);});

bar.append("text")
    .attr("class", "text")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value) - 3; })
    .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.value; })
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "14px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end");
```

This is what I want to do:

[image: US Government analytics chart]

**EDIT**

I have made some progress. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Monduiz/drhdtsaq/33/

Now I need to find how to move the ordinal categories between the bars.

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't work for me. It looks like the solution is the simple one you've outlined though.

Comment: I made a small update earlier but it works for me, now. Thanks Lars for your input. I might try to add a blank grey bar at the full value to recreate the full grey bars. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got close enough after some attempts. I can polish things up with CSS.

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Monduiz/drhdtsaq/66/

Basically, the solution is to create another set of rectangles called first using a second set of data to full value of the scale used. Then its just a matter of adjusting the size of the bars and positioning the labels.

```
 bar2.append("rect")
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand()-15)
    .attr("fill", "#EDEDED")
    .attr("width", function(d){return x(d);});

bar.append("rect")
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand()-15)
    .attr("fill", "#FFB340")
    .attr("width", function(d){return x(d.value);});
```